# Test varargin for existence string pattern

Tags: matlab, validation, input

I have a function that takes `varargin` with a flexible number of inputs of different types. I want to check the variable for the existence of a certain string/substring e.g.

```
regexpi(varargin,'test');
```

this works for `varargin={'a','b'}` however it fails if there are other datatypes. How can I easily (fewest codelines) get a logical matrix that tests for the existence of `test`? here's something annoyingliy convoluted I came up with:

```matlab
varargin={'a',1,'test',{2}};
logi=num2cell(zeros(size(varargin))); %logical vector 'is string present or not';
logi(cellfun(@isstr,varargin))=regexp(varargin(cellfun(@isstr,varargin)),'test'); 
%outputs a cell array where numbers > 0 represent 'string found'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this, which is similar to your code but simpler:

```
varargin = {'abcd', 'efg', [1 2 3 4], {10; 20}};
pattern = 'bc';
result = cellfun(@(x) ischar(x) && ~isempty(regexpi(x, pattern)), varargin);
```

Note how the use of `&&` in the anonymous function prevents the test to be applied to non-char arguments.

Comment: Edit: **mmmmhhh beautiful!** I was under the impression anonymous functions don't allow `&&` operators, this opens up a ton of new possibilities

Comment: @user2305193 Glad you like it :-)

Comment: is there a way to report a value aside from booleans if the first condition (ischar(x)) is true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What value would that be? Starting position of the matching? Or just an additional Boolean value based on the `ischar`condition only?

Comment: basically what I want is an if statement within a anonymous function, if ~isempty(x), return(x).            
 `isempty(x) || x` doesn't really work

Comment: @user2305193 So, _if_ `x` is not empty _then_ return `x`, _else_...?

Comment: I guess empty or zero would be easiest to work with

Comment: If empty is fine there is not need for the `if`, is it? Just return `x`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `isequal` for a quick fix

```
bTest = cellfun( @(x) isequal( x, 'test' ), varargin );
```

A more verbose solution might be to use the `inputParser` and standard "name-value pair" syntax which is present in a lot of MATLAB functions.

```
function myFunc( varargin )
    % 'option' is the name of this optional parameter
    % varargin = {'option', 'test'}; 

    p = inputParser();
    p.addOptional( 'option', '' ); % Optional parameter, default to empty
    p.parse( varargin{:} );
    p.Results.option % = 'test' for the example varargin
```